# npm start command is not working when I will run react-js project

Tags: reactjs

I am installing react for the first time. I don't know what can I do.

Reference image of error.
https://prnt.sc/x7ys01

Thanks in advance.

Solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63672963/14988182

Comment: you're not in the folder of your project

Comment: can you show your folder structure?

Comment: D:\reacttut\awesomeapp

Comment: awesomeapp is my project name

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Your Console address should look like this when you're running the `npm start` command:

```
D:\reacttut\awesomeapp>
```